# how to delete a row in Python dataframe related to a specific column where values with specific character e.g., starts with letter "E" exist?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame (df) where there is a column called "Hole_ID", within this column there are some values start with letter "E" e.g., E1, E2, E3, E4. I need to remove the rows where these values exist

I tried

```
df = df[df.hole_ID.iloc[:1]!='E'].reset_index(drop=True)
```

but it gives me the following indexing error:

```
IndexingError: Unalignable boolean Series provided as indexer (index of the boolean Series and of the indexed object do not match).
```

Comment: As the closed duplicate answer states, use: `df[~df.hole_ID.astype(str).str.startswith('E')]`